# Import files into a directory on a HTML document

Tags: html

I am wondering if I can have a webpage where I can tell it to grab my file and put it in a directory, such as: "http://example.ex/folder". Meaning the file I provided is put into the "folder" folder.

Overall process:

1. Button says: "Import file"
2. I select a file, and my file is "text.txt"
3. It takes my file "text.txt" and adds it to the local system/directory of the website.

Comment: Please provide more details as to what kind of website and framework you are using. How you accomplish this depends a lot on what you are running on the back end.

Comment: Are you familiar with node.js or another server-side language?

Comment: @itsanewabstract No

Comment: @MichaelHawkins It is my own Raspberry Pi Apche2 server

Comment: @MacintoshFan Ah, I see. Well to do something like this will require you to have a server setup to handle uploading the file. You can use an html `form` element and an `input` element of type `file` to get a user's file on the frontend, but attaching it to the website's directory requires custom logic that only the server can handle

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JQuery File Upload and then adding a backend service that captures the file and saves it.

For example, here is a repository that has a basic Python (Flask) server integrated with JQuery File Upload that will take an uploaded file and place it on the server:

https://github.com/ngoduykhanh/flask-file-uploader

I'd put the rest of the code here, but it is a lot - and requires HTML, JavaScript and a back-end language (like Python).

Here is the documentation on JQuery File Upload: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

As a word of caution, **DO NOT TRUST ANYTHING UPLOADED TO YOUR SERVER**. Meaning, do not put it out on the open internet without some sort of authentication or checks in place to make sure only files you intend are uploaded. Otherwise, people will find it and upload scripts turning your device into a Bitcoin miner, spam relay, or bot host.

Instead of doing it this way, why not use SFTP to upload it to your server to host? At least that way you can lock down access.